CEC issue - tx error 64 when a device is on
So, I've installed cec-utils on bookworm and am trying to communicate with an AV receiver.
When the device is in standby, an echo "on 5" | cec-client -s -d 1 would turn it on (hurray!) but after that nothing that I would try to send would work any more.
In fact, when the receiver is on, even echo "scan" | cec-client -s d 1 would start returning a bunch of errors. Errors are focused on same "ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64" some seconds after "Opening a connection to the CEC adapter...". It seems like every once in a while it manages to "get through" to something, so sometimes I get coherrent messages on some of the devices in the HDMI network, but mostly it's error messages. When the receiver is in standby, everything seems to work as it should.
Raspberry sits in one of this receiver's input ports (HDMI 6) and audio works just fine.
